# Initialising ChartJS with dataset index[0]

Tags: chart.js

I've written a python script to get data from Google Search Console, stores it etc etc and print out an html output. The whole thing works really well and I've used buttons to select different datasets to hide/show them as you click on them.

I have no idea how to initialise the chart with index[0] though, all datasets are being rendered and shown when the page is loaded. I've had a look through the documentation but this is way over my head. Is there something in the options I can call to just show one dataset right from the start?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="m-5">
      <div class="card col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>



<div class="listSelector">
      <ul>
      <button onclick="toggleData(0)">https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/</button><br>
      <button onclick="toggleData(1)">https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/blog/</button><br>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.min.js"></script><script>const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');const myChart = new Chart(ctx,
      {type:"line",data:{labels:['2022-07-16', '2022-07-17', '2022-07-18', '2022-07-19', '2022-07-20', '2022-07-21', '2022-07-22', '2022-07-23', '2022-07-24', '2022-07-25', '2022-07-26', '2022-07-27', '2022-07-28', '2022-07-29', '2022-07-30', '2022-07-31', '2022-08-01', '2022-08-02', '2022-08-03', '2022-08-04', '2022-08-05', '2022-08-06', '2022-08-07', '2022-08-08', '2022-08-09', '2022-08-10', '2022-08-11', '2022-08-12', '2022-08-13', '2022-08-14', '2022-08-15', '2022-08-16', '2022-08-17', '2022-08-18', '2022-08-19', '2022-08-20', '2022-08-21', '2022-08-22', '2022-08-23', '2022-08-24', '2022-08-25', '2022-08-26', '2022-08-27', '2022-08-28', '2022-08-29', '2022-08-30', '2022-08-31', '2022-09-01', '2022-09-02', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-04', '2022-09-05', '2022-09-06', '2022-09-07', '2022-09-08', '2022-09-09', '2022-09-10', '2022-09-11', '2022-09-12', '2022-09-13', '2022-09-14', '2022-09-15', '2022-09-16', '2022-09-17', '2022-09-18', '2022-09-19', '2022-09-20', '2022-09-21', '2022-09-22', '2022-09-23', '2022-09-24', '2022-09-25', '2022-09-26', '2022-09-27', '2022-09-28', '2022-09-29', '2022-09-30', '2022-10-01', '2022-10-02', '2022-10-03', '2022-10-04', '2022-10-05', '2022-10-06', '2022-10-07', '2022-10-08', '2022-10-09', '2022-10-10', '2022-10-11', '2022-10-12', '2022-10-13', '2022-10-14', '2022-10-15', '2022-10-16', '2022-10-17', '2022-10-18', '2022-10-19', '2022-10-20', '2022-10-21', '2022-10-22', '2022-10-23'],datasets: [
      {label: "https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/", data: [4551, 5072, 5426, 5224, 4672, 4257, 4035, 4376, 4680, 4916, 4957, 4929, 4786, 5391, 5390, 5991, 5463, 5308, 4739, 4450, 4577, 4831, 5045, 5006, 4609, 4098, 3720, 4300, 5185, 5251, 4503, 3757, 3971, 3967, 3772, 3619, 3585, 3601, 3485, 3454, 3497, 3431, 3602, 3732, 4574, 4470, 4393, 3541, 3397, 3458, 3564, 3823, 3897, 3682, 3158, 3081, 3395, 4089, 4502, 4664, 4866, 4398, 4098, 3845, 4018, 4149, 4272, 4324, 4285, 4085, 4403, 4754, 5957, 6702, 7324, 7109, 7209, 7477, 7800, 7785, 7639, 7195, 6739, 6729, 7143, 7481, 7313, 6630, 6127, 5847, 6239, 6811, 7285, 7335, 7139, 6941, 6663, 6233, 4054, 1937],fill: "start", backgroundColor: ['rgba(90, 204, 204,0.4)'], borderColor: ['rgba(90, 204, 204, 1)'], borderWidth: 2 },
      {label: "https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/blog/", data: [75, 88, 123, 116, 92, 62, 39, 59, 87, 90, 83, 55, 53, 37, 51, 77, 99, 83, 61, 41, 32, 30, 35, 35, 34, 28, 30, 21, 20, 17, 32, 40, 43, 38, 29, 33, 33, 47, 56, 49, 34, 17, 14, 19, 23, 31, 25, 17, 7, 17, 28, 39, 57, 55, 47, 21, 20, 22, 20, 22, 26, 29, 22, 21, 26, 48, 62, 63, 47, 35, 33, 33, 30, 32, 36, 37, 29, 27, 21, 22, 21, 24, 33, 25, 37, 35, 44, 34, 29, 20, 13, 23, 44, 52, 42, 32, 32, 27, 13, 2],fill: "start", backgroundColor: ['rgba(90, 204, 204,0.4)'], borderColor: ['rgba(90, 204, 204, 1)'], borderWidth: 2 },


]},options: {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display:false
          }
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }}}});
      
      function toggleData(value) {
        const showValue = myChart.isDatasetVisible(value)
        if(showValue === true) {
          myChart.hide(value);
        }
        if(showValue === false) {
          myChart.show(value);
        }
      }
      </script>
```

My script can produce hundreds of datasets, I've shortened it to 2 here because of the size of the label and data arrays.

I'm missing a function or method call. I would like the very first dataset to be shown, then as I click on different buttons the chart to refresh. I think I can do that, I'm just looking for the initialisation of the chart.

Comment: If I have understood well, you can add the "hidden: true" option to the second dataset. Here is the code pen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/BaVyGGg

Comment: Amazing! 14 characters and problem solved. Thank you.